# Need help extracting objects from deep arrays and combining into one single array

Tags: javascript, node.js

What's the best way to extract the objects with the `target` properties and combine them into one array?

**app.js**

```
const p1 = [[{ target1: 3 }, { target2: 1 }], [{ t: 2 }]];
const p2 = [[{ target1: 1 }, { target2: 2 }], [{ t: 2 }]];
const p3 = [[{ target1: 4 }, { target2: 1 }], [{ t: 2 }]];
const p4 = [[{ target1: 2 }, { target2: 2 }], [{ t: 2 }]];


Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then((values) => {
    console.log(values);
    // Some way to extract the objects that have the target property in them 
    // and combine them into a single array
});
```

**results**

```
[ [ [ [Object], [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ],
  [ [ [Object], [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ],
  [ [ [Object], [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ],
  [ [ [Object], [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ] ]
```

**desired**

```
[{ target1: 3 }, { target2: 1 },
{ target1: 1 }, { target2: 2 },
{ target1: 4 }, { target2: 1 },
{ target1: 2 }, { target2: 2 }]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Small explanation along with code snippet will make your question nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal with the code below.

```
const p1 = [[{ target1: 3 }, { target2: 1 }], [{ t: 2 }]];
const p2 = [[{ target1: 1 }, { target2: 2 }], [{ t: 2 }]];
const p3 = [[{ target1: 4 }, { target2: 1 }], [{ t: 2 }]];
const p4 = [[{ target1: 2 }, { target2: 2 }], [{ t: 2 }]];

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then((values) => {
   const [a1, a2, a3, a4] = values

   const [t1] = a1;
   const [t2] = a2;
   const [t3] = a3;
   const [t4] = a4;

   const result = [...t1, ...t2, ...t3, ...t4];

   console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping over the array and using deconstruction:

```
let transformedValues = Array.prototype.concat( //poor man's one level flatten when combined with ...
  ...values.map(([[target1, target2]])=> [target1, target2])
)
```

I'm assuming the number of `p` values varies, but the structure of the `p` values is constant.